# Compiling multiple C files in a program

Tags: c, compilation, linker

I have the following two files:

**file1.c**

```
int main(){
  foo();
  return 0;
}
```

**file2.c**

```
void foo(){

 }
```

Can I compile and link the two files together so the `file1.c` will recognize the `foo` function without adding `extern`?

Updated the prototype.

> gcc file1.c file2.c throws: warning: implicit declaration of function foo.

Comment: `gcc file1.c file2.c`, also I don't know C's exact rules for function calls when it's not seen a prototype but you might have to add `int foo();` above `main`

Comment: @Seth: please always -include `-Wall` when giving gcc examples - it helps to get noobs into good habits.

Comment: I updated the question. I do it with -Wall.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need an `extern`, but file1.c must see a declaration that `foo()` exists. Usually this declaration is in a header file.

To add a forward declaration without using a header file, simply modify file1.c to:

```
int foo();  // add this declaration

int main(){
  foo();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: can I do it without any header files just by compiling the two together?

Comment: You still need a forward declaration of `foo()`, which you could do in file1.c if you want.

Comment: @mary yes, header files are for the compiler but this is done by the linker

Answer (score 52):

The correct way is as follows:

`file1.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "file2.h"

int main(void){
    printf("%s:%s:%d \n", __FILE__, __FUNCTION__, __LINE__);
    foo();
    return 0;
}
```

`file2.h`

```
void foo(void);
```

`file2.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "file2.h"

void foo(void) {
    printf("%s:%s:%d \n", __FILE__, __func__, __LINE__);
    return;
}
```

`output`

```
$
$ gcc file1.c file2.c -o file -Wall
$
$ ./file 
file1.c:main:6 
file2.c:foo:6 
$
```

Comment: The C99 pre-defined identifier is `__func__`. Prefer this to the gcc specific `__FUNCTION__`.

Comment: I don't think it's good practice to pass the header to the compiler like that - if it's needed, the preprocessor will bring it in.

Comment: @TimothyJones My apologies. That is a nice point. Thanks for keeping a check on the answer! .. I have corrected it now!

Comment: Also please always include `-Wall` in any gcc command line example.

Comment: @PaulR What's the -Wall for?

Comment: @Minuet: it tells the compiler to enable all warnings - compiler warnings are really helpful and important, particularly for people who are still learning the language, but unfortunately they are not enabled by default, Always compile with warnings enabled and pay attention to any warnings that the compiler omits.

Answer (score 7):

You *can*, but you shouldn't.

Use a header file, file2.h:

```
// file2.h

void foo(); // prototype for function foo()
```

Then add:

```
#include "file2.h"
```

in file1.c

To compile:

```
$ gcc -Wall file1.c file2.c -o foo
```

As a general rule it's better (more robust) to use a header file to define the *interface* of each *module* rather than *ad hoc* prototypes within dependent modules. This is sometimes known as the SPOT (Single Point Of Truth) principle.

Comment: You don't need `extern` for calling a function, you only need the prototype, like `int foo();` in the header and the body in `file2.c`

Comment: @Seth: true - you don't *need* it, but there is nothing wrong with making it explicit.

Comment: I've never seen anyone make a function `extern` just because it's in another file. Saying you _can but shouldn't_ write a function in another file without using `extern` on the prototype is completely baseless, unless you know something I don't (which is likely)

Comment: @Seth: not at all - the prototype is `extern` whether you explicitly declare it `extern` or use C's implicit rules. I put it there to make it clear for noobs that it's a prototype, but mostly people don't use the explicit `extern` declaration form these days.

Comment: Then why do you tell him that he shouldn't write a function that is to be used in other files without writing `extern`? The word "shouldn't" is too strong here

Comment: @Seth: if you want to encourage good software engineering practices then you need to promote separation of interface versus implementation for each module. I'll take the `extern` out of you prefer - it's only there for clarity but clearly it bothers you.

Comment: I had no problem with the `extern`, it's telling someone what they _should_ do here. As I said, I've never seen this before, ever. Have you? I don't see where _should_ is backed up by anything. Usually when you tell someone what they _should_ do, you also present reasons why they should, and I can't see any reason at all for this, not even "because everyone else does it"

Comment: @Seth: I've added some clarification to justify the "should" - *ad hoc* prototypes really should be discouraged.

Comment: Is there some external source that also advocates using `extern` on all prototypes? (i.e. that also says you should always use `extern`)

Comment: @Seth: pretty much any decent introductory textbook on software engineering should cover this - I don't have a specific example at hand that I can cite though.

Comment: Note that until you are using C23, the line `void foo(); // prototype for function foo()` in `file2.h` provides a declaration of fucntion `foo()` but does NOT provide a prototype for the function.  The empty parentheses say "takes an undefined list of arguments, but is not a variadic function (like `printf()` — there is no `, ...` at the end of the prototype)".  Providing a declaration is sufficient to allow the function to be called in C99, C11, C18.

Answer (score 4):

It's ugly, but using gcc, you could:

```
gcc -include file2.c file1.c
```

`-include` is a flag to the preprocessor which will include the contents of file2.c at the very top of file1.c. Having said that, it's a poor choice, and breaks down for all but the simplest of programs.