# Can you include header file into another header file but when including the second header file in .c file, not automatically include the first one?

Tags: c

If I had a header file named "Header1.h" and another header file named "Header2.h", and include the first header file into the second, Header1 -> Header2, I would have access to Header1's code from Header2 .  (For example, if I had defined a struct inside Header1, I could now make variables of that struct type in Header2).

Now if I had a .c file named "Main.c" and if I include "Header2.h" in "Main.c", Header2 -> Main, I would be able to access Header2's code from Main, but I would also be able to access Header1's code from Main as if I have included "Header1.h" inside "Main.c" specifically as well, Header1 -> Main. (For example, I could make a variable of type struct [the one defined in "Header1.h"] inside "Main.c").

Is there a way for me to restrict such access to "Header1.h" from "Main.c" and allow only "Header2.h" to be able to access information from "Header2.h", and perform similar "privatization" of a header file?

Transcribing a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74830266/can-you-include-header-file-into-another-header-file-but-when-including-the-seco/74830297#comment132062300_74830297) into the question:

**`Header1.h`:**

```
void printLinkedListImpl(Node* head)
{
    while (head) {
        printf("%d ", head->data);
        head = head->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

**`Header2.h`:**

```
typedef struct {
    Node* head;
    int size;
    void (*printLinkedList)(Node*);
} LinkedList;

LinkedList* LinkedListConstructorImpl() {
    LinkedList* linkedList = (LinkedList*)malloc(sizeof(LinkedList));
    linkedList->head = NULL;
    linkedList->size = 0;
    linkedList->printLinkedList = &printLinkedListImpl;
}
```

**`Main.c`:**

```
void runner() {
    LinkedList* linkedList = LinkedListConstructorImpl();
}
```

Comment: What parts of Header1 are required by Header2?  That makes a huge difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two main options:

1. `Header2.h` needs the contents of `Header1.h`, in which case you can't sensibly want to omit the contents of `Header1.h`.
2. `Header2.h` does not need the contents of `Header1.h`, in which case `Header2.h` should not include `Header1.h`.

Write the code using the headers according to which option applies.

You would need a good reason not to decide on one or the other of those two options.  However, it might be possible to define the header guard for `Header1.h` before including `Header2.h`:

**`Header1.h`**

```
#ifndef HEADER1_H
#define HEADER1_H
…
#endif
```

**`Header2.h`**

```
#ifndef HEADER2_H
#define HEADER2_H

#include "Header1.h"

…

#endif
```

**`Main.c`**

```
…
#define HEADER1_H
#include "Header2.h"
…
```

But, as I stated at the outset, either `Header2.h` needs the information from `Header1.h` to compile (in which case this will cause a compilation failure), or it doesn't (in which case `Header2.h` should not include `Header1.h`).

<sup>*After transcribing the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74830266/can-you-include-header-file-into-another-header-file-but-when-including-the-seco/74830297#comment132062300_74830297) into the question:*</sup>

Header files should not define general functions like it appears `Header1.h` does.  A header should declare functions, types, enumerations, macros — and may perhaps define `static inline` functions — but should not define variables or functions.  (See also [How do I use `extern` to share variables between source files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1433204/15168)). If you define functions in a header, the header can only be used by one source file, but the whole point of a header is to share information between source files.

If you're not sure how to build programs from multiple source files, that is a different question — one which has been answered many times.  For example, [Compiling multiple C files in a program](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8728728/15168), and there are numerous questions and answers for different IDEs that can be found by searching on SO with `[c] compile multiple files program`.

Comment: **Header1**:
`void printLinkedListImpl(Node* head) {}`
**Header2**:
`typedef struct {
 Node* head;
 int size;

 void (*printLinkedList)(Node*);
}LinkedList;

LinkedList* LinkedListConstructorImpl() {
 LinkedList* linkedList = (LinkedList*)malloc(sizeof(LinkedList));
 linkedList->head = NULL;
 linkedList->size = 0;
 linkedList->printLinkedList = &printLinkedListImpl;
}`
**Main.c**:
`void runner() {
 LinkedList* linkedList = LinkedListConstructorImpl();
}`

Comment: If header2 needs some stuff from header1, but not other stuff from header1 and you don't want to include that stuff every time you include header2, maybe header1 should actually be header1a and header1b.

Comment: @Chris what i want is an inability for someone to say in "Main.c" something like:
`printLinkedListImpl(arg);`

Comment: @starter_dev — (1) I've transcribed your comment into the question, which is where you should have put the contents of the comment in the first place.  (2) You should not be defining functions (other than `static inline` functions, perhaps) in a header.  If you define functions in a header, the header can only be used by one source file, but the whole point of a header is to share information between source files.